# Adicionar e remover campos dinamicamente com soma e multiplicação dos valores

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho uma página, onde o usuário deverá colocar a quantidade e o valor de cada item. Ele poderá acrescentar quantos itens ele quiser.
Em baixo na página, mostrará o resultado total da soma de todas as possíveis linhas que o usuário adicionar.

Vejam o Fiddle a seguir para compreenderem melhor.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f0aggozk/1/

Essa estrutura esta praticamente finalizada.
O único problema que esta acontecendo, é que ao ao acrescentar um novo campo, se algum dos valores estiverem vazios, o valor total exibido fica vazio.
Creio que seja necessário fazer o cálculo por cada uma das linhas, e somar o valor de todas as linhas.

Comment: precisa ser com jquery puro? Existem alguns frameworks que fazem isso bem fácil.

Comment: Estou aberto a alternativas, mas creio que o meu código faltam só alguns detalhes para ele ficar rodando sem bugs.

Comment: O problema é que quando adiciona uma linha nova está zerando total? Se sim, sua validação para setar o total para **zero**  na linha 46 esta zerando o total. Se o total da última linha for zero, você está zerando o total. Fiz um pequeno ajuste veja aqui se está ok: https://jsfiddle.net/5z0qavps/1/.

Comment: Na verdade não era ao adicionar uma nova linha o problema. O cálculo acontecia quando alterava o input. Ao mantê-lo vazio ou apagar, acontecia o bug de zerar tudo. Porém a validação que você acrescentou realmente resolveu. Adicione como resposta da pergunta, por favor. :)

Comment: @MauroAlves que bom que funcionou, adicionei como resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @cbonomini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validação onde você está zerando o total, está no lugar errado.

Você deveria validar depois do laço que fez a soma, e testar se `amount_sum` é zero para zerar o total. E testar o `total` apenas para confirmar se considerará na soma total.

```
function somarValores() {
    var amount_sum = 0;
    //calculate total worth of money
    $('.linha').each(function(){;
    var custo = $(this).find(".custo").val();
        var custoConvertido = parseFloat(custo.replace(",", "."));
        var quantidade = $(this).find(".quantidade").val();
        var total = custoConvertido * quantidade

        //testa se o valor da linha é > 0 para considerar na soma;
        if (total > 0){
            amount_sum += parseFloat(total);
            sum = amount_sum.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ',');
            console.log(amount_sum);
            console.log(sum);
        }
    });
    //teste se a soma total for zero
    if(amount_sum == 0)
        sum = "0,00";
    else
        sum = amount_sum.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ',');

    $('#valor').html(sum);
}
```